# installed mcrypt but still undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()

Tags: apache, mcrypt, php-ini, php

I have :

1- installed `mcrypt`

2- checked `phpinfo();` and doubled checked that php.ini is my app config file.

3- got mcrypt path from my `/usr/local` which is `/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.29/mcrypt.so` , and included it in my `php.ini` which is the ini file for my application like the following :
`extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.29/mcrypt.so"` .

4- restarted with `sudo apachectl restart`

and after restarting apache the error still appears :(

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()`

what am I missing here?

Comment: So _did_ the output of `phpinfo()` show up the module or not?

Comment: And did you get any mentioning of the module in the http servers error log file upon startup or not?

Comment: @arkascha thanks for ur comment, I have checked now, there is no mention in the `phpinfo()` for the module.  the error of undefined mcrypt_create_iv() is appearing in my virtualhost error log, there is no other mention for the module itself

Comment: If you configured the module to be loaded, no error is thrown when it _should_ be loaded, but it obviously _is_ not loaded, then apparently you made a mistake in configuring the extension.

Comment: Apart from that: why do you still use a totally outdated and deprecated php version with all it's security issues?

Comment: I have only done the above steps, any other configuration is needed? @arkascha I think this is a preinstalled version... the thing is I only need to run this application locally and make my app use it's domain for registration. ..after solving this error..could you guide me through this ?

Comment: Something under `/usr/local` certainly is nothing "preinstalled". That looks like a "wild installation" instead. What distribution are you working on? Why don't you use the software management system instead, since you apparently are using a Linux OS?

Comment: I see, I'm on OS X El Capitan. I can see it now in `phpinfo()` - I have added `;` before the extension= in php.ini .. not sure if that helped or I missed it the first time. but I see it in the output : `mcrypt Sascha Schumann, Derick Rethans` .. the error is still there

Comment: If you place a `;` in front of a directive in that configuration file then that directive is _commented out_. That should be explained at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Ok, if you are using OSX then you do not have a software management. You indeed have to install things manually then with all the pitfalls that brings ;-(

Comment: okay so the module is loaded but the function is undefined,,, that means maybe there is a step to enable the module? what do u think @arkascha

Comment: If the module is loaded, then it is enabled. No further step is required. But something is fishy in this which is why I did not post another comment. If you commented out the directive to load the module, then it certainly will not suddenly get loaded.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.